# Android Launcher Icon doesn't load

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

Doing a routine update to an app and decided to update the launcher icon as I have done many times before. However, I'm getting a very strange bug which I had once before but can't remember how I resolved.

I have the right sized icons in each drawable folder and in the manifest the name is correct:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

When I try to update the app the old icon remains, on a fresh installation the default launcher icon shows.

I've tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Restarting Eclipse
- Restarting my computer
- Restarting the device
- A different device
- Adding a new set of icons using the Android Icon Set function
- Adding a new set using a different filename and changing the name in the manifest

One stange thing that is worth pointing out, if I delete the file ic_launcher.png from a drawable folder, then rename another file to that filename I get this error:

[image]

This shouldn't show as the file doesn't exist. This error then shows if I click continue:

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT:

It appears this issue is even more complex than I thought. If I install an app on the emulator the icon appears just fine, on a device it doesn't. If I install the app onto physical devices from the apk, on one device the icon appears and on the other the Package installer crashes!

Comment: I faced the same issue twice. Leave the existing set of icons as it is. Copy paste new set of icons to your drawable folders with new name(Other than ic_launcher). Change the icon name in Manifest file. That works for me. @Leon

Comment: @Pooja yep I've tried this too. Copying into the Drawable folder via Eclipse, via Finder or using the Android Icon Tool and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seem this is caused by a bug in newer versions of Android. The icons are indeed included in the apk and upload just fine to Play, however it takes a reboot to get them to be shown on my devices (I was wrong above where I said a reboot doesn't work). This means I need to reboot the devices each time I try and new icon, not the end of the world but certainly frustrating.

This problem exists on two different apps I have been working on and two different Nexus devices, I think since they were updated to 5.0.